# Likelihood ratio test in R for categorical variables

Tags: r, categorical-data, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, likelihood-ratio

I am working with behavioral data of male sea lions, with a binomial model to understand the effect of different variables in determining the location where the encounters between males occur (Land -vs- water). For this I have several quantitative and categorical variables.

I am testing the significance of the odds ratio for each variable using likelihood ratio tests.

For my dataset the variable "Temperature" was divided into 3 different categories: "1" values<20ºC, "2" values between 20ºC and 30ºC, and "3" values>30ºC.

The results of the odds ratio shows that the odds of an aggressive interaction occurring on the land increase in 9% when going from the first temperature interval (<20ºC) to the second interval (20ºC-30º). However, the odds of an aggressive interaction occurring on land decrease in 8% when going from the second temperature interval (20ºC-30º) to the third interval (>30ºC).

When applying the likelihood ratio test (lrtest function) to these data it gives me a single value of P, but what I need is one value for each change of the variable: one for the change between the first and the second interval, and one for the change between the second and the third interval.

It means I need the likelihood ratio test to include the categorical variable, to understand the significance of each odds ratio.

The script I used is this one:

```
# MODEL WITH ALL VARIABLES

> J_mod.a <- glm(as.factor(Place) ~ as.factor(TempF) + as.factor (AgType) + FemDen,  data=JUNE, family=binomial("logit"))
> J_mod.a

Call:  glm(formula = as.factor(Place) ~ as.factor(TempF) + as.factor(AgType) + 
FemDen, family = binomial("logit"), data = JUNE)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)   as.factor(TempF)2   as.factor(TempF)3  as.factor(AgType)2  
 1.34820             0.08229            -2.53280            -1.73712  
 FemDen  
 0.11443  

Degrees of Freedom: 124 Total (i.e. Null);  120 Residual
(7 observations deleted due to missingness)
Null Deviance:      159.6 

# MODEL WITHOUT TEMPERATURE

> J_mod.TEMP <- glm(as.factor(Place) ~ as.factor (AgType) + FemDen, data=JUNE,   family=binomial("logit"))
> J_mod.TEMP

Call:  glm(formula = as.factor(Place) ~ as.factor(AgType) + FemDen, 
family = binomial("logit"), data = JUNE)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  as.factor(AgType)2              FemDen  
 0.01463            -1.77035             0.08361  

Degrees of Freedom: 124 Total (i.e. Null);  122 Residual
(7 observations deleted due to missingness)
Null Deviance:      159.6 
Residual Deviance: 129.4    AIC: 135.4


# LIKELIHOOD RATIO TEST BETWEEN THE 2 MODELS

> J_LRT_TEMP <- lrtest (J_mod.a, J_mod.TEMP) 
> J_LRT_TEMP

Model 1: as.factor(Place) ~ as.factor(TempF) + as.factor(AgType) + FemDen
Model 2: as.factor(Place) ~ as.factor(AgType) + FemDen

L.R. Chisq         d.f.            P 
2.371378e+01 2.000000e+00 7.089530e-06
```

I thank you in advance for all of you who can take some of your time to let me know what am I doing wrong, or what am I missing here.

Best.

Answer (score 3):

I post this as an answer, because I do not have the privilege to comment.

The LR-test compares two different models, which could differ not only in one predictor but possibly in many. The result of your test tells you, that the model including the variable temperature better fits the data compared to the model without it. The test has two dfs because you dropped two betas.

If you are interested in comparing the different levels of the variable temperature, `summary(J_mod.TEMP)` will give you the p-values. Note that `R`uses dummy coding by default, so the first coefficient contrasts level 2 vs. 1 and the second coefficient level 3 vs. 1. You may use `contrasts` to adapt this to your personl needs.